# iframe issue with jQuery mobile , frame is reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, iframe, cordova

I am developing a hybrid application using **jQuery mobile** and **phonegap** , In my application I am loading a page that contains an **iframe**. But what really happening is when I am loading it in the  android emulator the page is loading and the frame is overlapping the page (Kinda second loading),when I click the back button and restarting the app then it will work fine .. I have seen some solutions regarding modifying cordova.plist but it didn't work with me , Can anybody help me?  I am using **cordova 2.4.0**

Giving my HTML below,  I am getting the output right but the frame is overlapping first time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Account</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
#main{
    padding: 1em;
    position : absolute; 
    top : 0;  
    right : 0; 
    bottom : 0;  
    left : 0;     
}
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="pageone" data-theme="a">

<!-- Header -->

<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" align="center" data-theme="b"><h1>BANK NAME</h1>
<a href="home_page.html" data-role="button"  data-theme="b" rel="external" >Back</a></div>

<div data-role="main">

<div class="ui-field-contain" align="center">
<a href="atm_search_location.html" target="mapview" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">ATM</a>
<a href="branch_search_location.html" target="mapview" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-inline="true">BRANCH</a>
<a href="atm_branch_near_map.html" target="mapview" data-role="button" data-theme="a"  data-inline="true">NEAR ME</a>
</div>
<div>
<iframe name="mapview" width="100%" height="950px" src="my_current_location.html"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's easier if you can show us a portion of your code regarding this problem.

Comment: @Tamura : Of course please see the edits ..